# How to hide folders on Ubuntu Apache, people access to /css on my website

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, ubuntu-14.04

my problem is that you can access to mydomain.com/css, I use Laravel 5.0 on a Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2.

Is there a way to deny access to this folder? and just let people have access to the resources if they know the exact URL.

For example:
mydomain.com/css DENY ACCESS
mydomain.com/css/home.css PERMIT ACCESS

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your users need to have access to the content of the css directory, but they don't need to list the files in this directory.

For this you can add :

```
<Directory /path/to/css>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

in your configuration files. You can also just add `Options -Indexes` in the corresponding `.htaccess`. It will disable indexing.

Read :

- https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options

  for more information.